# Why my query runs fast on mgmt studio but slow in application for specific parameters?

Tags: sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have this query (generated by Entity Framework 4 for MSSQL 2008R2):

```
SELECT 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Limit1].[Text] AS [Text], 
[Limit1].[Sender] AS [Sender], 
[Limit1].[Time] AS [Time], 
[Limit1].[Status] AS [Status]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (100) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Sender] AS [Sender], 
    [Extent1].[Time] AS [Time], 
    [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[DeleteStatus]) 
        AND ([Extent1].[OwnerId] = @p__linq__0) 
        AND (1 = [Extent1].[Cateogry])      
        AND ([Extent1].[Id] > @p__linq__1)
)  AS [Limit1]

-- @p__linq__0=123, @p__linq__1 = 1234
```

This gets executed (from application, via EF) in less than 50ms for all queries except a query with some specific parameters. With those parameters, the query takes more than 20 seconds (every time) to execute although the result set returns zero rows. When I run the same query in the management studio, it takes 0 ms. The plan (both estimated and exact) shows like this:
[image: Query Plan]

The SQL-Server profiler shows this query corresponding to that:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Limit1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Limit1].[Text] AS [Text], 
[Limit1].[Sender] AS [Sender], 
[Limit1].[Time] AS [Time], 
[Limit1].[Status] AS [Status]
FROM ( SELECT TOP (100) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Sender] AS [Sender], 
    [Extent1].[Time] AS [Time], 
    [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[MyTable] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (0 = [Extent1].[DeleteStatus]) AND ([Extent1].[OwnerId] = @p__linq__0) AND (1 = [Extent1].[Cateogry]) AND ([Extent1].[Id] > @p__linq__1)
)  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 bigint,@p__linq__1 bigint',@p__linq__0=123,@p__linq__1=1234
```

The table in question has these concerned indices:

```
PK___1(Id) -- Clustered, Column [Id] is bigint
IX____OwnerId_Category(OwnerId,Category,Status) -- Included-Column: DeleteStatus
```

What could be the reason for this? How can I fix it?
By the way:

- Table contains 50M+ rows.
- Statistics are updated on daily basis.
- Indices are rebuilt in 3/4 days when fragmentation is over 20%.

Reading from other posts, I executed these (without understanding, of course. I was just looking for a quick fix.):

- `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS`
- `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`

But it is all same.

Comment: Try adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) as a query hint. It definitely sounds like you have Parameter Sniffing going on. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: But this is a normal query (Linq To SQL, generated by EF). If parameter sniffing was happening, that should happen to numerous other queries, right? Why just for a particular query with particular parameters?

Comment: Dont know much about EF but from what i'm seeing in your execution plan you could change IX____OwnerId_Category to include the selected column to get rid of that key lookup.It might help

Comment: Read the link and you'll understand... some types of queries are particularly susceptible to parameter sniffing and some are not. Recently I worked with a system with hundreds of EF queries and only _one_ of them had a parameter sniffing issue.

Comment: A comprehensive classic must read with almost the same title as your question: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links in the comments are great: 1)[Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) and 2)[The Elephant and the Mouse, or, Parameter Sniffing in SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)

Not that I understood all those; but I got rid of this by converting that dynamic SQL into a stored procedure which uses index hint.